# Procedure If exists update else insert em tabela com chave composta SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Olá.

Estou querendo sincronizar uma tabela com o Linked Server, porém o problema é que a tabela tem chave primária composta, e não sei como fazer a verificação para buscar o registro.
Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?!

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Desta forma que vou lhe mostrar garante a integridade dos dados com o uso do transaction, veja se isso lhe ajuda:

```
begin tran
if exists (select * from Sua_tabela with (updlock,serializable) where key1 = @key1 and key2 = @key2)
begin
   update Sua_tabela set ...
   where key1 = @key1 and key2 = @key2
end
else
begin
insert Sua_tabela (key1, key2 ...)
values (@key1, @key2, ...)
end
commit tran
```

ou

```
begin tran
   update Sua_tabela with (serializable) set ...
   where key = @key and key2 = @key2

   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
      insert Sua_tabela (key1, key2, ...) values (@key1, @key2, ...)
   end
commit tran
```